# MonoRail: how to remove prototype validation?

Tags: validation, castle-monorail

I'm maintaining an application with monorail, and we decided to change the validation method for the Jquery one. So far so good, but... the problem i'm having is that i can't get rid of the reference to the previous validation method which is prototype.

Thing is that a Javascript is always placed after the tag forms i create.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (!window.prototypeValidators) prototypeValidators = $A([]);
var validator = new Validation('form1', {onSubmit:true, focusOnError:true, stopOnFirst:false, immediate:true, useTitles:true});
prototypeValidators['form1'] = validator;
</script>
```

I haven't been able to find clear documentation about monorail validation methods.

And this turns to produce some errors on the browser like so:

```
$A is not defined
[Break On This Error] if (!window.prototypeValidators) prototypeValidators = $A([]);
```

Any help or pointers in the right way for documentation about this or how to remove this kind of validation from monorail, will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

MetalGeorge

PS. i gotta say i'm fairly new to monorail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can switch to jQuery generation (default is Prototype as you noted) with the  JSGeneratorConfiguration property in the Monorail config. See http://hammett.castleproject.org/?p=238 for reference.

Or you can get rid of form validation generation completely by replacing:

```
$Form.FormTag("%{action='LoginAction'}")
...
$Form.EndFormTag()
```

with a regular form tag:

```
<form method="post" action="$Url.For("%{action='LoginAction'}")">
...
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks on the reply, but i can't find any JSGeneratorConfiguration sentence on the code :S.

Comment: @MetalGeorge: have you seen the article? have you implemented IMonoRailConfigurationEvents and set the config there?

Comment: Yes, i've seen it, but i don't have the IMonoRailConfigurationEvents interface available. 
I've searched on the references but it's not there :S.
I'm using version 1.0.3.0 maybe that's the main problem. Besides the integration with jquery i'm handling it only by using links on the default layouts.

Comment: @MetalGeorge: yup, I think you can't change the generator in 1.0.3.0 (RC3) :-(

Comment: @MetalGeorge: how are you defining your forms? can you post a sample form?

Comment: @Mauricio, that's the thing i'm only defining like this:

<pre>$Form.FormTag("%{action='LoginAction'}")
...
$Form.EndFormTag()</pre>

And that's enough for having the javascript for validation.

Comment: Well thought... it does the trick!!!
Thanks a lot man!!
And a happy new year !!!!